# How can I edit file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to:

-edit the data of a .dat file on my computer for a website.

-pull data from the file to use it later on.

I know a tiny bit about javascript and heard javascript cannot directly edit databases.

Is a .dat file in my computer a database?

I have done a few things in Javascript for websites but I haven't done anything complicated completely myself. I created some websites before and I have a basic understanding of HTML and CSS.

Please phrase your response as simply as possible. Explain the meaning of any complicated but necessary terms.

Comment: It depends on how you create the `.dat` file. Where does the file come from? Why do you need JavaScript to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some server-side script to access the filesystem of the server such as PHP or NodeJs...

Nodejs example here.

```
let fs = require('fs');
```

Appeding file:

```
fs.appendFile('mynewfile1.txt', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```

Delete file:

```
fs.unlink('mynewfile2.txt', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('File deleted!');
});
```

Read file :

```
fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: the above script only supports ASCII files, but not binary files.

Comment: Of course, you can change from binaray to ascii or ascii to binary, isn't it?